# Getting select button in div tag instead of input

Tags: javascript, html

I have a bit of confusion. Suppose we want to add a button in html we normal do it in this way:

```
<input name="" class="" type="button" value="Select..."/>
```

but if want same select button in div tag how this can be done

I know this is quite silly, but I can't figure out.

Comment: Just... wrap `<div></div>` tags around the button? It's pretty unclear what exactly you're asking...

Comment: if you want to do this using javascript check this link  http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3565578.htm

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
 <div>
    <input name="" class="" type="button" value="Select..."/>
 </div>
```

Note : button is type of input.